# Risk neutral Esscher transform of exponential Levy processes

Tags: modeling, risk-neutral-measure

Let $X_t$ be a Levy Process and $e^{X_t}$ the corresponding exponential Levy process. Using the Esscher transform for a change of measure for which the Radon-Nykodym derivative is 
$$\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}} = \frac{e^{\theta X_T}}{E[e^{\theta X_T}]},$$

I am looking to find the Esscher parameter $\theta$ such that the measure $\mathbb{Q}$ is **risk neutral**, i.e. such that the following equation is satisfied:
$$
E^{\mathbb{Q}}[e^{X_T} \vert \mathcal{F}_t] = e^{X_t}
$$
where $T>t$ and $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the filtration at time t. My goal is to find an explicit formula for $\theta$ in terms of characteristic functions of the Levy process.

**What I have tried:** 
Using Bayes' rule  $$ E^{\mathbb{Q}}[X \vert \mathcal{F}] = \frac{E^{\mathbb{P}}[ X f \vert \mathcal{F}]}{E^{\mathbb{P}} [f \vert \mathcal{F}]}
$$
where $f$ is a Radon-Nykodym derivative $dQ/dP$,
we get $$
E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[ \frac{e^{\theta X_T}}{E^{\mathbb{P}}[e^{\theta X_T}]} e^{X_T} \bigg| \mathcal{F}_t \right]\frac{1}{ E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[ \frac{e^{\theta X_T}}{E^{\mathbb{P}}[e^{\theta X_T}]} \big| \mathcal{F}_t \right]} = e^{X_t} \Leftrightarrow\\
E^{\mathbb{P}} [e^{(\theta +1) X_T} | \mathcal{F}_t] = e^{X_t} E^{\mathbb{P}}[e^{\theta X_T} | \mathcal{F}_t]$$ Since $e^{(\theta+1)X_t}$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable, this can be written $$ e^{(\theta +1 )X_t} E^{\mathbb{P}}[e^{(\theta +1)(X_T-X_t)} | \mathcal{F}_t] = e^{X_t} E^{\mathbb{P}}[e^{\theta X_T} | \mathcal{F}_t]$$ By stationarity of increments of the Levy process this can be written $$
e^{\theta} E^{\mathbb{P}}[e^{(\theta +1)X_{T-t}} | \mathcal{F}_t] = E^{\mathbb{P}}[e^{\theta X_T} | \mathcal{F}_t]
$$
Now by making the substitution $\theta +1 = iu$ we rewrite the equation in terms of characteristic functions:
$$
e^{\theta} e^{(T-t)\psi(u)} = e^{t\psi(u)}E(e^{-X_T}|\mathcal{F}_t)
$$
Where $\psi$ is the characteristic exponent. This is almost what I need, except the extra expectation. What to do with it? I have a somewhat limited knowledge of filtrations for continuous time models so I am not sure whether the above calculations are correct either.

Comment: are you sure that your application of the Bayes' rule is correct ?

Comment: also how do you arrive at $e^{X_t}$ in the second equation ?

Comment: pretty sure about the Bayes' rule (the calculations involving it are basically mere algebraic operations). The $e^{X_t}$ comes from the risk neutral valuation principle that $X_t = E^Q [X_T | \mathcal{F}_t]$ where $T$ is the end date. I have removed the discount factor for simplicity.

Comment: okey now I see it - I will think some more on the topic :)

Comment: The equation 
$$E^{\mathbb{P}} [e^{(\theta +1) X_T} | \mathcal{F}_t] = e^{X_t} E^{\mathbb{P}}[e^{\theta X_T} | \mathcal{F}_t]$$

does not hold. You can't just factor out $e^{X_T}$ by doing  $ E^{\mathbb{P}}[e^{\theta X_T+X_T} | \mathcal{F}_t] = e^{X_t} E^{\mathbb{P}}[e^{\theta X_T} | \mathcal{F}_t]$

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you saying that the manipulation $$E[e^{\theta X_T} e^{X_T} | \mathcal{F}_t] = E[e^{X_T (\theta + 1)} | \mathcal{F}_t]$$ is illegal? Otherwise, the only operations that are performed between the plugging in into Bayes'f formula and the equation you mentioned, is factoring out $E[e^{\theta X_T}]$, which is a constant.

Comment: no what yo write is - look at my equation it is different. it is also what you wrote in your main post. You cannot just factor out the $e^{X_T}$ from the conditional expectation by applying the martingale property to the factor. To be precise $E[e^{\theta X_T} e^{X_T}|F_t]\neq e^{X_t} E[e^{\theta X_T}|F_t] $

Comment: The equation $E [e^{(\theta +1) X_T} | \mathcal{F}_t] = e^{X_t} E[e^{\theta X_T} | \mathcal{F}_t]$ is just the previous equation in rewritten form. I.e. it is derived almost directly from the Bayes' rule.

Comment: I see it and I still just don't understand how Bayes' rule can be applied here ? What am I missing ? Are we talking about the same rule ?  http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~norman/BBNs/Bayes_rule.htm

Comment: yes and no :) this is a generalization of the usual Bayes' rule, where we use the Radon-Nykodym derivative to compute conditional expectations

Comment: do you have a source ? Also do you assume that $e^{X_t}$ is a martingale under $\mathbb{P}$ ?

Comment: You can find it in You-Kuen Kwok's "Mathematical Models of Financial Derivatives", exercise 2.43. I know there is not much written about it in general, it is a somewhat esoteric topic :) $e^{X_t}$ is not a martingale under $\mathbb{P}$, but it is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable, so, for some random variable $Y$, we have $$ E[e^{X_t}Y| \mathcal{F}_t] = e^{X_t}E[Y|\mathcal{F}_t] $$

Comment: according to your reference it should be $$ E^{\mathbb{Q}}[X \vert \mathcal{F}] = \frac{E^{\mathbb{P}}[ X f \vert \mathcal{F}]}{E^{\mathbb{P}} [f \vert \mathcal{F}]}
$$  This is different from what you wrote above - but you apply it correctly later on :)

Comment: this is also what one uses in change of numerarire tecnique - I was not aware that it was also called the generalized Baye's rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution to this problem by posting an excerpt of it at math.stackexchange: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716242/equation-involving-expectations-of-levy-processes

Answer (score 1):

In the paper [OPTION PRICING BY ESSCHER TRANSFORMS](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~dbackus/Disasters/Gerber_Shiu_94.pdf) the authors explore this topic extensively and provie equations that enable the calculation of the risk neutral $\theta$.

Also note that you can easily deal with the expectation in 
$$
e^{\theta} e^{(T-t)\psi(u)} = e^{t\psi(u)}E(e^{-X_T}|\mathcal{F}_t)
$$

if the process $X_t$ itself has nice properties. One could solve it in the GBM cases. A solution should also be attainable **if the process' transition density is known** explicitly.